# MAX RETURN QUESTION MARK IN PYTHON (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, data-science, data-analysis

I'm having a problem with my code

```
            data = pd.read_table('household_power_consumption.txt',sep=';', 
                                  low_memory=False,header=0, index_col=False,
                                  parse_dates=[0])
            df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=None)
            col = df["Global_active_power"]
            max_value=col.max()
            print(max_value)
```

This is an image of the dataset [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27rKg.png)

As you can see, the column **"Global_active_power"** is fully occupied with data. However, my max value return **a question mark** **("?")**

I have tried several codes but the value stays the same. Can somebody help me with this

---

You can get the data from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption

Comment: The data in the column is `str` type.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not all of the rows in column **Global_active_power** are populated by numerical values.
Probably the latest value in the row has missing value and there populated is "?".
Because of that entire column is not numerical, and **max()** returns the latest value from the row.

Check example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3], "y": ["32.32", "?","fef"], "z": ["32.32", "456", "?"]})

df

# output
   x      y      z
0  1  32.32  32.32
1  2      ?    456
2  3    fef      ?


df.x.max()

# output
3

df.y.max()

# output
'fef'

df.z.max()

# output
'?'
```

If column is not numerical data type, **max()** all the time returns the latest value in the column.

Comment: thank you, I have just realised that I haven't cleaned the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the column, as imported, is `str` type -- so `.max()` isn't meaningful in the sense you intend.  It appears that the data is floating-type, so you need to convert it to type `float64`, but first replace all the `?` values with `NaN` (so the type conversion doesn't fail). That is, try:

```py
col = df['Global_active_power'].apply(lambda x: x if x != '?' else 'NaN')
                               .astype('float64')
```

Working example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table('household_power_consumption.txt',\
                     sep=';',low_memory=False,\
                     header=0, index_col=False,parse_dates=[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(data,dtype=None)
col = df['Global_active_power'].apply(lambda x: x if x != '?' else 'NaN')\
                               .astype('float64')
print(col.max())

>>> 11.122
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have just realised that I haven't cleaned the dataset